# I'm unable to edit my profile

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

I'm trying to complete my profile, since I've been led to believe I will earn another badge by doing so... So I go to the "edit profile & settings" page and add a few simple text-only things (location: "Wisconsin".... and "writer & editor" in the "about me" box. I try to save, but I get an error message that says "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Invalid image type." What am I doing wrong? Or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try changing [the file format of] your avatar?